# Booting Ubuntu 13.04 i386 from USB, main OS is Windows 7, VAIO S Series, VPCS149FJ

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04

I'm also one of the newbies at Ubuntu and I intend on installing Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop i386 on my USB using Universal USB Installer, with some basic information provided on

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

which doesn't, unfortunately, provides me with information about what to do after creation. Do I just shut down, plug the USB in, start up, interrupt normal booting, choose booting device which is the USB, and done?

Even if this succeeds, when I shut down in Ubuntu, do I start up at Windows 7 the next time?

What is the difference between **'trying'** Ubuntu and **'installing'** Ubuntu? I've heard that it's possible to perform an **installation** on a USB. How?

A LOT OF INFO is appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the USB, you need to boot from it.  Just change the boot order in your BIOS to boot from USB.

Since you have Windows 7 installed already, when you get to the installation screen, choose alongside Windows.

[image]

Trying Ubuntu lets you run Ubuntu fully, but without making any changes to your system, while installing will do changes to your system, depending on the type of installation you choose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this picture **trying** or **installing**? Does installing mean that I can't save anything on Ubuntu?

Comment: The image is for installing Ubuntu.  Trying it will just boot into the desktop.  What do you mean saving?  Once installed you can save documents, files, music, downloads, etc.

Comment: OK I think I got it! :)

Comment: With your info I read the support by SONY and it said by pressing F11 continuously it will boot from CD / DVD / USB drive.

Comment: I believe that's right.

Comment: Does this installation screen appear after I boot from USB?

Comment: The first screen that you get gives you the option of Installing Ubuntu or Trying it.